# A Question on Bohr's model of atom

Tags: energy, electrons, atomic-physics

When an electron revolves around a nucleus, It uses its energy in form of kinetic energy and so it release energy and then moves . It means that it release energy continuously, Otherwise, if it does not release energy(in form of Kinetic energy) continuously. Then its motion around nucleus is not possible.Please make me understand this concept?

Comment: The Bohr model was a stepping stone towards good models of electronic structure. It has several flaws, one of which you have noted. Please search the site before asking a duplicate. And, firmly push the Bohr model out of your mind as a current theory.

Answer (score 4):

Do you expect the moon to fall on the earth soon, from loosing its kinetic energy? If there is no interaction (as with tides for example) kinetic energy is conserved  and the moon will still be turning around the earth, even though it is moving away due to the tidal interαction, when the sun becomes a giant dwarf. This is because the moon is captured  around the earth by the gravitational force, a very weak force in comparison to the electromagnεtic one, but effective for large masses.

The planetary model for the electron around the nucleus fails because of the nature of the electromagnetic interaction: an accelerating charge radiates away energy , as the Maxwell equations show. The electron in orbit has angular acceleration and it will radiate electromagnetic waves, classically , and fall in the nucleus. So the planetary model fails since atoms exist and are stable .

The [Bohr model](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bohr_model) **postulated**  stable orbits in the planetary model, i.e. radiation forbidden for orbits with transitions fitting the data for the [hydrogen atom.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hydrogen_atom) It has been superseded by quantum mechanics and the solutions of the Schrodinger equation for the Hydrogen atom.

Comment: On this, I think that atoms would collapse but due to releasing smaller and smaller energy continuously , it would collapse very late..What about the bridges break with time period of about 100 years...and building too after long time?? Please make me Understand it???

Comment: It would not be slow,  the loss of energy in the planetary model would be continuous and fast. have a look at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bremsstrahlung which is the classical radiation from a charged particle in a field .